# rm: Directory resources is not empty

Tags: directory, rm, aix

I'm getting this kind of error when i'm deleting file on my AIX machine.  Getting same error for `rmdir`.

```
pwd
/hm/dev/application/backup/ear

rm -rf resources
rm: Directory resources is not empty.
```

I tried to find out the hidden files using `ls -lart` under `resources` and `ear` directory. But there are no hidden files.

Comment: Does `find` show anything? Others report problems deleting NFS-mounted directories on AIX, or having to run fsck to deal with broken directory entries.

Comment: any related error running errpt -a ?

Comment: Does `resources` have a filesystem mounted on it?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, /ear is mounted .. I successfully deleted all the sub dir and files under /ear directory except resources/.

Comment: there may be a process holding a filehandle open under that directory; try fuser and/or lsof to investigate.

Comment: If it's a deleted file with an open filehandle, you might only be able to see its inode number and PID of the process via `fuser -dV /hm/dev/application/backup/ear/resources`
You could then try to search for the inode via ncheck command and also check the process if it can be killed. *Although if that process runs in kernel space you cannot kill it at all and a reboot may be necessary.*

Answer (score 1):

One of the cases this happens is that when there's an application keeps writing to the directory, so the command will remove the directory contents and tries to remove the directory itself but fails because new contents have been written.

When I experienced this, I searched for the application that keeps writing to it, stop writing new files and the directory remove got executed successfully. You can use

```
lsof | grep /my/directory/path
```

to find the application that does this.